# como commitar um repositório clonado?

Tags: git, github, bash

Ontem criei um repositório no github e dei alguns commits, hoje já em outra máquina clonei um repositório e estou tentando commitar alterações porém não consigo.

processo... que fiz até agora

```
$ git clone 'repositorio'

$ git init
```

//fui no repositório e adicionei um novo arquivo...

```
$ git status

$ git add -A

$ git push origin master    <- aqui dá erro
```

> ERRO: fatal: No configured push destination. Either specify the URL
>   from the command-line or configure a remote repository using
>
> ```
> git remote add <name> <url>
> ```
>
> and then push using the remote name
>
> ```
> git push <name>
> ```

Comment: Você clonou por SSH?

Comment: Atualize minha resposta, deixe-me saber se alguma das soluções funcionou!

Comment: clonei por HTTP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você estiver usando o `Git Bash`. Você tem que garantir que está no arquivo mestre. Usando o comando `cd foldername`:

[image]

`git log` mostra as alterações detalhadas feitas

Você pode usar este comando para confirmar alteraçõe:

```
git commit -m "descrição de alterações"
```

e estes comandos para salvar as alterações no repositório online:

```
git push -u origin master
git pull origin master
```

`git push -u github master` definirá sua ramificação mestre local para rastrear a ramificação principal no controle remoto do github.

Da próxima vez que você enviar este ramo, você poderá usar o comando mais curto `git push`.

para corrigir todos os ramos de uma só vez:

```
git push -u github --all
```

> a resposta está no erro:
>
> ```
> git remote add <nome do arquivo> <url>
> git push <nome do arquivo>
> ```
>
> exemplo:
>
> ```
> git remote add nomedoarquivo 'git@github.com:repositorio/nomedoarquivo.git'
> git push nomedoarquivo
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Se foi feita exatamente a sequência descrita, existe um erro ao fazer:

```
$ git clone 'repositorio'

$ git init
```

O primeiro comando já cria o repositório e deixa pronto para uso, o segundo comando vai criar um repositório dentro do repositório, e se estiver na raiz vai ficar inconsistente.

O segundo comando é usando somente para criar localmente um repositório Git, quando você executa em uma pasta vazia ele irá criar os arquivos ocultos necessários para a pasta ser reconhicida e funcionar como um repositório Git.

O comando clone já deixa nesse ponto, não é preciso iniciar um repositório, pois quando ele é clonado, ele já foi inicializado.

Answer (score 0):

```
git status
```

Se estiver vermelho as arquivos , digite

```
git add nome do arquivo mais extensão , ou se quiser add todos os arquivos 
gitt add . 

git status
```

Vera que estão verdes porque não precisam ser adicionados

```
git commit -m 'teste'
```

Para comitar

```
git push -u origin master
```

Envia

```
git pull origin master
```

Recebe

A casos que terá que por o nome do servidor no lugar de origin

Uma maneira mais fácil e

```
git commit -am 'teste'
```

Ele add e comita junta pulando a fase de adicionar

Outra dica e ver se esta conectado ao repositório

Para testar

```
git remote -v
```

caso não esteja só seguir esse tutorial

https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Git-Essencial-Trabalhando-com-Remotos

Comment: executei o $ git remote -v  e não me retornou nada